# My function with array as parameter does not work

Tags: arrays, postgresql, parameters

I proceed to specify my question and the solution I gave to the problem, for the benefit of the community.
I was trying to perform a multi-column insert using the identifier with a function.
For which, I was getting an error, my code was the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION acc.asignar_periodo(ids NUMERIC[], periodo INTEGER,codigo_subdiario VARCHAR) 
  RETURNS void 
  VOLATILE 
AS
$$
DECLARE
cant_registros integer:= 0;
BEGIN
    cant_registros := array_length(ids,1);
    FOR i IN 1..cant_registros LOOP
        EXECUTE'UPDATE '||$3||' SET periodo_tributario = $2  WHERE id = ids[i]';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and my query is:

```
SELECT acc.asignar_periodo('{2291,2292,2293,2294,2295,2296,2297,2298,2299,2300,2301,2302}'::NUMERIC[],201612,'_08');
```

My solution was the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION acc.asignar_periodo(INTEGER[],INTEGER,INTEGER) RETURNS text VOLATILE AS
$$
DECLARE
qty integer:= array_length($1,1);
respuesta varchar := null;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..qty LOOP
        EXECUTE'UPDATE _'||$3||' SET periodo_tributario = '||$2||' WHERE id = '||$1[i];
    END LOOP;
    respuesta := 'Periodo '||$2||' asignado a '||qty||' comprobantes del subdiario '||$3;
RETURN respuesta;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note the correction, since when using EXECUTE it is necessary that the arguments escape the statements

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the _exact_ and complete error message you get.

Comment: Reading the docs is a good start. From here [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN): `...WHERE id =  $1' USING ids[i]`. As of now your statement is resolving to `... WHERE id = ids[i]` with a literal `ids[1]` instead of `..WHERE id = <actual_value>` where <actual_value> comes from `ids[i]` and as the error says there is no column `ids[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no to loop needed to process the array. Postgres will process the entry array at once. After all set processing is what SQL is all about.  Get into the mindset that whenever you write `loop`, likely incorrect and much slower. (Yes there occasions where it is necessary, but very few.) So: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/CkicJIfQ))

```
create or replace function asignar_periodo(ids numeric[], periodo integer,codigo_subdiario varchar) 
   returns void 
  language plpgsql
as $$
declare 
   stmt constant text = 'update %I set periodo_tributario = %s where id = any (''%s'')'; 
   torun text; 
begin
    --torun = format(stmt, $3, $2, $1);                      -- this would work but 
    torun = format(stmt, codigo_subdiario, periodo, ids);    -- I perfer parameter names to position reference
    raise notice '%', torun; 
    execute torun;
end ;
$$;
```